# Splitting n weighted objects in m disjoint sets such that maximum of sum of objects in a all sets is minimal

Tags: algorithm, graph, division

Suppose that there are n objects with different weights. We need to divide all objects in m sets.  Let S<sub>i</sub> be sum of i<sup>th</sup> set, 1<= i <=m. S<sub>max</sub> be maximum of all S<sub>i</sub>'s. What can be the algorithm to minimize S<sub>max</sub> over all possible divisions of n objects in m sets.

I have seen some algo which used Hungarian algorithm and bipartite graphs but could not understand that.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the backpack problem. What qualities are you looking for in an algorithm? Do you understand the Hungarian algorithm? Do you understand bipartite graphs?

Comment: I know bipartite graph. I think there can be some optimized algorithm rather than finding sums iterating through all combinations.

Comment: If you can solve this, you can solve the [partition problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: ... and more importantly, the [3-partition](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're asking about is **NP-Complete**, as it can be reduced to the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (and the [3-parition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem)). To see why, suppose **m = 2** and that the sum of weights of all objects is *S*. If the first set's sum is *S<sub>1</sub>*, then obviously the the other set's sum *S<sub>2</sub>* = S - *S<sub>1</sub>*. Let's prove that if we can make *S<sub>1</sub>* and *S<sub>2</sub>* equal (the solution to partition problem), then this is the optimal solution for your problem.

If *S<sub>1</sub>* = *S<sub>2</sub>* wasn't optimal, that means that there exists some way of partitioning such that the first set has a sum *S<sub>1</sub>'* that would yield a better solution (a smaller maximum number). Let's consider two cases:

- *S<sub>1</sub>'* < *S<sub>1</sub>*. In that case, -*S<sub>1</sub>'* > -*S<sub>1</sub>* and thus S - *S<sub>1</sub>'* > S - *S<sub>1</sub>*. Therfore the new maximum is larger (worse) than in the case of equal sums.
- *S<sub>1</sub>'* > *S<sub>1</sub>*. In this case, it immediately follows that the maximum in the case of the new partition is larger (worse) than in the case of equal sums.

Similarly, you can show how you can reduce you problem to the 3-paritition problem. However, there are some heuristics that can help in solving the partition problem, you can read about them in the Wikipedia pages I linked to earlier; I doubt there's anything better than brute force for your more-generic version (unless there's some kind of restriction you didn't mention).

Hope that helped you in any manner!